# Weird rescaling issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, scintilla

Im trying to add an element to my form, its not showing up in the toolbar thats why im doing it programatically, and its from the NuGet search. Its called SimpleEditor from EasyScintilla, which is derives off the Scintilla class, and here's my code for it.

```
TextField = new EasyScintilla.SimpleEditor()
        {
            Size = new Size(1151, 516),
            Location = new Point(194, 82),
            CaretLineBackColor = Color.FromArgb(38, 38, 38),
            Lexer = Lexer.Lua,
            CaretForeColor = Color.FromArgb(38, 38, 38),
            AdditionalCaretForeColor = Color.FromArgb(38, 38, 38),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
            Styler = new LuaStyler()
            {
                Lexer = Lexer.Lua,
                AutoIndent = true,
                CodeFolding = true,
                ShowLineNumbers = true,
            },
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | 
            AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom,
        };
```

So it lets me add it in, and for the most part it's okay. But for whatever reason as soon as I change a element in the design page, it freaks out. Its supposed to look like this:

(Ignore the button that's for a test I was doing)
[image: Supposed to look like]

But as soon as I change something in the design, even so much as the text color for a button or something, I need to undo parts of my code in order to revert it back to the way it's supposed to look, no matter what that code is (Even comments). Anyways, this is what it looks like when it's glitched out like this:

[image]
(And yes, the buttons at the bottom get cut off too). It remains like this no matter how I resize it and the tab on the right just isn't there at all (Its hidden off to the far right). I don't know if the issue is Visual studio or it's something in my code (Because I didn't change anything in my code that would cause this before it started). If anyone knows why this problem is occurring help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project? Sometimes form controls need that in order to display correctly or show up in the toolbox.

Comment: No I have not, But I just did after you said that and it did nothing :(